# Draw table, and put div with specific class to new row

Tags: html, css, tabular, flextable

I have some rendered data, and I want to display it "in table".
How can I implement this using CSS? (Maybe flex could help me)

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="newRow">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="newRow">5</div>
<div class="test">6</div>
```

Expected result, something like this:

```
1 3 5 

2 4 6

*
```

Divs are rendered by angular2 loop (ngFor). There may be 2 or more. I need more dynamic solutions which would be depends on "class="newRow"" - end of row.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>This table has no borders:</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try this:

```
<div>
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
  display:inline;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d0Ltnenp/2/

Comment: Divs are rendered by angular2 loop (ngFor). There may be 2 or more. I need more dynamic solutions which would be depends on "class="newRow""  - end of row.